# touch.facebook.com on iPhone giving me "Entity 'nbsp' not defined"

Tags: xml, ios, facebook, xhtml

Just as I found a way to access my app's profile page on touch.facebook.com, thanks to [logan](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7948019/app-profile-page-versus-m-facebook-com) and this url format...

```
http://touch.facebook.com/profile.php?id=myappid
```

...I ran into this new problem. It worked fine for a while, and then all of a sudden for no apparent reason, instead of my app profile, iOS Safari only shows a red warning box telling there's an error called "Entity 'nbsp' not defined".

I Googled it and found out it's a [common XHTML error](http://techtrouts.com/webkit-entity-nbsp-not-defined-convert-html-entities-to-xml/) that's mostly ignored by everyone except XML strict browsers – like Apple's Safari. Ok, so there's the problem – solution: just convert my non-breaking spaces to XML entities.

The only downside is, they're not my nbsp's – for sure I had no need to use either HTML or XML markup in what little text I have in my app description etc.

**So, it's got to be touch.facebook.com itself, right? If this is correct, I wonder if there's any way to work around this problem?**

Or, is falling back once again to the plain old m.facebook.com version my only option? I sure would like to use the touch version if possible, since it works and looks so much better than m.facebook.com.

This is so weird, Facebook sharing is just 5% of my iPhone app's functionality, and yet it seems to be taking 50% of my overall development time. What's up with that?

Comment: Indeed, the touch.facebook.com/profile.php has defined a XHTML doctype, and yet it's using nbsp entities all over. I'm not a XML expert, but if one's to believe the techtrouts link above, isn't this just plain wrong? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found Facebook's (old) announcement from march 2011, stating the sites will be unified to a single address: m.facebook.com. I couldn't find the official FB announcement again, so here's a third party news: http://www.allfacebook.com/facebook-unifies-mobile-site-for-250-million-users-2011-03#idc-container

So, I'll just use the m.facebook.com even if it's a lot duller. Questions still remain, though: why is touch.facebook.com still there? Why is it still providing a different looking UI than m.facebook.com and not just another domain name for the same, unified site? Whatever is 0.facebook.com? Why do I need to google for snippets of info and 3rd party rumors for hours to know what url to use to access Facebook mobile? How can FB customer/developer communication suck this bad?

[edit: minor typo corrections]